# Multiple file uploader - looking at Google Docs implementation

Tags: asp.net, upload, google-docs, multifile-uploader

I'm looking to implement a multiple file uploader in my ASP.NET 3.5 site.

Now, the Google Docs multi-file uploader is pretty awesome, and I'd like to create something like that. Correct me if I'm wrong, but Google Docs is not open source, so I can't get my hands on the source code for it.

Any ideas on how this is implemented, or the best way of creating a nice interactive multi-file uploader like it?

Comment: All HTML, CSS and JS is open-source - look at what it's doing client side at least.

Comment: @Kelix: GoogleDocs uses a combination of Flash and JS, with the bulk of the work happening in the Flash object, rather than the JS, and they heavily minify their JS to make it smaller to download, and also harder to read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess 'Zhaph - Ben Duguid' had the best answer for this one. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it!

> GoogleDocs uses a combination of Flash and JS, with the bulk of the work happening in the Flash object, rather than the JS, and they heavily minify their JS to make it smaller to download, and also harder to read...

Comment: More likely the JavaScript is generated via the Google Web Toolkit, which cross-compiles Java to JavaScript: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/

Comment: It's probable that they've updated the upload mechanism since last year, but what interests me is that it now works without Flash *and* without refreshing the page — similar to Uploadify or SWFUpload (but without the Flash).  I'm really curious how they're able to do this, as I would love to stop using SWFUpload.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest you give this jquery file upload plugin a try: "[uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)". It makes it super easy to integrate such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Nice and interactive : you can build a Silverlight client to send your files to webserver. It allows to select multiple files at once.

Comment: The main downfall of Silverlight is that very few people have it installed on their machine. So it is still highly recommended to stick with flash.